# XPS Document Print Tiling

Tags: printing, xps

Currently I have an XPS document whose width is too large for the paper. I would like it to print the clipped off contents on additional pages. I have not been successful at finding a setting to accomplish this.

Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to control this by using a PrintTicket or by working with the PrintQueue.  There isn't anything in the XpsDocument (other than the PrintTicket) that controls how the printer deals with this.

Answer (score 0):

Boyd,

I had the same problem with XPS documents created from Visual Studio DGML graphs. The parts of my solution to this I blogged about at http://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/convert-an-xps-to-jpeg-png-tiff-or-bmp-in-a4-pages/
This solution will tile the XPS into multiple A3, or A4, pages to a graphics file format, or into multiple pages in a TIFF file.